# RegistryKey - как удалить записи из массива

Tags: c#, реестр

У меня есть список значений которые нужно удалить

```
string[] spisok = new string[] { "Path", "GameDir"};
using RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(PathReg, true);
```

Как через Linq можно удалить все имена из раздела реестра?

Comment: Зачем вам тут `LINQ`? Его задача немного в другом. Если хотите конечно, то преобразуйте в `List` ваш массив, ну и пишите там `.ForEach(x=> ....)`, где `x` - это значение из массива, а `....` код удаления из реестра. Но не проще взять простой цикл `foreach` и пройтись самостоятельно?

Comment: Мне просто стало интересно)

Comment: Ну, тогда решение я вам сказал выше, дерзайте) Как удалять значения реестра я думаю вы и так знаете.

Comment: @aepot, отвлекся. Сегодня приму